XCode 15.2 issues with CMD+LEFT, not going to beginning of text, but beginning of whole line (column 0)
I recently reinstalled XCode 15.2, I am on Mac OS Ventura. and now this functionality is lost in the editor. Before, when I pressed CMD+LEFT ARROW, it went to the beginning of the first actual word on the line, which is what I want! Now it goes to the beginning of whole line. This is ruining my productivity, and I cannot get it back. How do I fix this? I tried going to XCode Settings->Key bindings and manually setting the shortcut for CMD+LEFT to be for "Move to beginning of text" but it doesn't do anything, and when I press CMD+LEFT, it just beeps and nothing happens. If I put it to "Move to beginning of line", then it does that, moves to beginning of line, not to the first word, which is very annoying. How do I return this functionality?

looks like a Ventura 13.7 bug: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/764992

Same here. Xcode 15.0 / MacOS Ventura. Have no idea what the beeps mean...lol. Have you found a solution?

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

@AndyGriffiths I see. Instead of answering, I should have left a comment with the question. Thank you for correcting me.

Not really. The site doesn't encourage 'me too' comments either. Comments are for clarifying questions and answers generally. Checkout https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment to see how we use comments here. Otherwise, welcome to Ask Different!
